# Auth session killed after redirect | laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I made a simple login form. I log my user with :

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);
```

But when I redirect the user to the ClientController I'm redirect to the login form, the Auth session is not persitent.

```
return redirect()->action('ClientController@index');
```

My routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'HomeController@auth');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web` middleware needs to kick in before the `auth` middleware because the `web` middleware is responsible for booting up your session. Switch the order around like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index');
});
```

However, while we're on this subject, you can nest route groups within another route group so to prevent an error like this in the future, I would just recommend nesting everything inside the `web` middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'HomeController@auth');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index');
    });
});
```